# Check if directory exists on FTP server

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I'm running a check to see if a directory exists on my FTP server:

```
    public bool DirectoryExists(string directory)
    {
        bool directoryExists;

        var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(directory);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");

        try
        {
            using (request.GetResponse())
            {
                directoryExists = true;
            }
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
            directoryExists = false;
        }

        return directoryExists;
    }
```

In this case:

```
directory = @"ftp://ftp.example.com/Rubicon";
```

On my server, I have a folder named `Rubicon1`.  This is causing my check to return `true`. How can I ensure that it fails unless it matches the directory name exactly?

Comment: can you get an list of directories in the parent? maybe it's hidden

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265953/how-can-you-easily-check-if-access-is-denied-for-a-file-in-net/265958#265958 The reasoning applies to any volatile resource, which definitely includes FTP shares.

Comment: @ericosg the line where it says `Create` is for creating the FTP web request, not the actual FTP Directory

Comment: just tried this with an FTP of mine and it works as expected. Could it be [their fault](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14635728/390819) again? :)

Comment: @w0lf, thanks i knew that, but phrased my statement terribly.

Comment: @w0lf: I've asked my web server provider to look into it, but they switched FTP services because of the last issue and are certain that everything is working as intended.  Personally, I've tried several different directory names, and if ANY of them contain `Rubicon`, the check passes.

Comment: Try to send `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory` for the desired path. If the response face failure, it'll return a `550` error about accessing or finding the relative file/folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I successfully solved this issue by changing my directory to be:

```
directory = @"ftp://ftp.example.com/Rubicon/";
```